# template function as argument to template function - unresolved function type error

Tags: c++, templates, eigen

I was trying to pass a function template F_1 that received a reference to an Eigen MatrixBase to another function template F_2 that would then, do something with it:

```
//Function that will be argument to F_2
template<typename derived_matrix,typename derived_float>
void F_1(const MatrixBase<derived_matrix>& x,derived_float t,MatrixBase<derived_matrix>& store){
  store = 2*x;
}

template<typename derivative_function,typename const_derived_matrix,typename derived_matrix,typename derived_float>
void F_2(derivative_function derivatives,const_derived_matrix x0,derived_float t0,derived_float dt,derived_matrix& output){ 
  //Do something with F_1(= derivatives)
  derived_matrix k1;
  derived_matrix k2;
  derived_matrix k3;
  derived_matrix k4;
  derivatives(x0,t0,k1);
  derivatives(x0+dt*k1/2,t0+dt/2,k2);
  derivatives(x0+dt*k2/2,t0+dt/2,k3);
  derivatives(x0+dt*k3/2,t0+dt,k4);
  output = x0+dt*(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)/6;
}
```

But I received the error "unresolved overloaded function type" from the F_2 function call:

```
double t  = 0;
double dt = 0.1;
Vector2d x;
x << 1,2;
Vector2d out_value;
F_2(F_1,x,t,dt,out_value); //unresolved overloaded function type
```

Reducing it to a minimum, I could only make a generic F_2 template function receive a F_1 function when it(F_1) is not a template:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

template<typename f,typename derived_float>
void F_2(f wrapped,derived_float x1,derived_float& x2){
  wrapped(x1,x2);
}

void F_1_works(double& x,double& store_output){
  store_output = 2*x;
}

template<typename T>
void F_1_broken(double& x,T& store_output){
  store_output = 2*x;
}

int main(){
  double out= 0;
  double x  = 25;
  F_2(F_1_works,x,out);  //compiles!
  F_2(F_1_broken,x,out); //Error: 
                         //      no matching function for call to ‘F_2(<unresolved overloaded function type>, double&, double&)’
                         //      couldn't deduce template parameter ‘f’
  cout<<out<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

1. How can I make the compiler deduce the type of "wrapped" in F_2(template parameter f)?
2. Would you have any suggestions to do it differently with Eigen?

Comment: `F_1` is a template function, the compiler can't deduce the template arguments out of thin air (i.e., you have to `F_2(F_1<??????>,x,t,dt,out_value);`).

Comment: is it possible to make it deduce the type from the function instantiation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
F_2(F_1_broken<double>,x,out);
```

The compiler has no way to deduce the type here.
So you have to help him :-)